# How to add number to textView on button click

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to build a simple calculator.
I need a method to put or display a number in a `textView` or `EditText`.

Something like:

```
Public void putNumbertoView(){
//puts the number to a textView
}
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `java.util*;`
You have to use conversion.

i.e.:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
      int x =Integer.parseInt("9");
      double c = Double.parseDouble("5");
      int b = Integer.parseInt("444",16);

      System.out.println(x);
      System.out.println(c);
      System.out.println(b);
   }
```

But instead of `System.out.print()`, you use `setText()` to a label/text:  `label1.setText(nameField.getText());`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void putNumbertoView(String num) {
    textView.setText(num + "");
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) 
        {

            case R.id.btn1:
                putNumbertoView("1");
                break;

            case R.id.btn2:
                putNumbertoView("2");
                break;
            ...
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,let me try it out.